# abbreviation for september and october in the 18c. English manuscripts

Tags: abbreviations

While I am reading a 18th c. manuscript, months of september and october are abbreviated as "7ber". I have not come across any other abbreviation for differing them. Can you please help me, is “7ber” September or October?

Comment: What else can you tell us about the manuscript? (country of origin, who wrote it, what kind of document, etc.) That *may* have a bearing on how to interpret the abbreviations.

Comment: Are you sure it's not *7ber* = September?

Comment: yes you are right actually, any clue for 7ber.

Comment: it is a Levant Company merchant document, who was in Aleppo in 1704 and wrighting about ship consigments to London.

Comment: If it is "7ber" ("septem" being the Latin word for 7), then one would expect "8ber" for October.

Comment: @StoneyB good thought!

Comment: With the misreading cleared up it seems the question answered itself (on the assumption that 7 = septem and 8 = octo is known).

Answer (score 1):

*7ber* is almost certainly just an abbreviation for September. The months from September through December come from the Latin roots for 7, 8, 9, and 10 (in the original calendar, March was the first month of the year, so September was the seventh month) with *-ber* appended. So this abbreviation simply replaces the Latin root with its actual number.

This is similar to using *7th* as an abbreviation for *seventh*, except that it's based on the original derivation of the word rather than its current meaning.

Comment: And to think people complain about youngsters using _l8ter_, _4u_ or _face2face_ in text messages. It's traditional!

Comment: "Julian calendar" is wrong. You mean the archaic form of the republican calendar.

Comment: @fdb I just assumed it was Julian, because of the Latin names and him being a Roman emperor. I changed it to just say original calendar.

Comment: The _-ber_ isn't really just a _-ber_. It's a haplologised version of _-member_, which is an _r_-stem derivation of _mens-_ ‘month’. So _septem(mem)ber_ is ‘the seventh month’, quite literally. (It is regular for _*s_ to become _*b_ before _*r_ in Latin.)

Comment: Regardless of where it came from, it's _-ber_ now. And that just gets copied into the abbreviation.

Comment: Julius Caesar was never a Roman emperor.

Comment: He was a Roman something. Is this a history site? :)

Comment: thanks all for great help and lots of informations about nameing months.